# Reledmac/Reledpar: Labeling translation paragraphs with line ranges instead of line numbers

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac, reledpar

**TL;DR Rather than number my translation's lines separately, I would like to label each translation paragraph with the line range of the original language verse they translate.**

It doesn't seem like reledmac/reledpar have a way to do this. I can manually change the right-side line numbers each time, but I don't think I can pass a string of the form "5-8" rather than an int.

I also tried using `\numberpstarttrue` and `\sidepstartnumtrue` on the right side to get per-pstart labels at least, but I run into the same string vs. int problem when trying to pass ranges to `\setcounter{pstart}{value}`. Maybe I could do something with line number annotation? But I'm not sure how to make it only affect the right side.

I'm relatively new to the packages, so I may just be missing something really obvious. Is there a built-in way to do this in reledmac/reledpar? Even if there isn't a built-in or elegant way, is there a brute force way to get it done (like manually inputting for each paragraph)?

Here is a MWE, though very little is implemented because I don't know where to start:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

% Set stanza indents
\setstanzaindents{8,5,6}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

\begin{document}
\large
    \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \begin{astanza}
                verse verse verse 1!&
                verse verse verse 2!&
                verse verse verse 3!&
                verse verse verse 4!\&
            \end{astanza}
             \begin{astanza}
                verse verse verse 5!&
                verse verse verse 6!&
                verse verse verse 7!&
                verse verse verse 8!\&
            \end{astanza}
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                This is a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. There is nothing interesting in here, please move on.  \textit{I would like "1-4" in the right margin in the same style as the left-side line numbers here.}
            \pend
            \pstart
                This is a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. There is nothing interesting in here, please move on. \textit{I would like "5-8" in the right margin in the same style as the left-side line numbers here.}
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot of how it renders:
[image: MWE basic double-sided verse]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's always best to add a small but complete, compilable example document to your question that can be used by others to reproduce the problem and as a basis to work on a solution.

Comment: there is no obvious way to that with reledmac/reledpar. There is maybe a solution, but I need a small example to start to think.

Comment: @Maïeul I put a small example above, though as I mentioned I haven't really implemented anything to play with, it's just the text itself

Comment: that is what i need

Comment: as you have verse, so fixed line number, you can just use \ledsidenote and related to print what you want in margin.

Comment: @Maïeul, that's perfect! I knew I had to be missing something deceptively simple. I'll still need to hide right-side numbering so it doesn't interfere with the labels but you already have an answer on that elsewhere on the site. Could you post this comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use verse, the line number of the left side is fixed. So you can simply use `\ledsidenote` on the right side.